# How can I use CellsPanelHorizontalOffset in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to define `DataGrid.CellsPanelHorizontalOffset` in XAML, how can I do it?

As far as I could understand I should define it by `DataGridCellsPanel`.

Answer (score 1):

`DataGrid.CellsPanelHorizontalOffset` is a dependency property, which has `public` getter and `private` setter. So without reflection you will not be able to set this property directly.

**BUT** you can set it indirectly, if you set **`DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth`**. In most cases it will be the same, but not always (the value is based on some conditions and being calculated in `DataGrid` internally).

Folllowing example should force `DataGrid.CellsPanelHorizontalOffset` to return 0:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="..." RowHeaderWidth="0"></DataGrid>
```

and of course you can do bind to the `DataGrid.CellsPanelHorizontalOffset`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" ItemsSource="..." RowHeaderWidth="100"></DataGrid>
<Label Background="DarkTurquoise" Width="{Binding ElementName=dg1, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"/>
```